# TinyMCE: New line on Enter, new Paragraph on double Enter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wysiwyg, tinymce-4

I am using [TinyMCE v4](https://www.tinymce.com).

If I press enter in the texteditor it looks like I have pressed enter twice:
[image]

And this is the generated source code:

```
<p>Test Line one</p>
<p>this is the next line after pressing enter</p>
```

If I press enter+shift, then its in new line
[image]

and thats the generated source code:

```
<p>Test Line one<br />this is the next line after pressing enter</p>
```

---

***Is it possible to change the editor in that way, that a single return creates a break `<br>` and a double return creates a new paragraph `<p>` ?*** 
So in short we would change

- Shift + Enter => Pressing enter once
- Enter => Pressing enter twice

This would be the same behaviour of `LibreOffice Writer` and thus a good thing for people who actually use a WYSIWYG editor.

The only thing I found was the option [forced_root_block](https://www.tinymce.com/docs-3x/reference/configuration/Configuration3x@forced_root_block/) to swap the commands, so enter creates `<br>` and shift+enter created `<p>`. However this is also very confusing for non-developer user, and also there is a warning that one should avoid this:

> Note that not using p elements as root block can severely cripple the
>   functionality of the editor.

Comment: Really feels like you have answered your own question.  They provide you a way but warn against it.  Chances are that it wrecks the editors built in way to style the text.  You could submit the request to them (don't think the project is open source) or find a different editor.

Comment: @Steve Wait they don't provide a way! The option that I have found makes it possible that you only create `<p>` with shift+ enter. But I want to create a `<p>` element with hitting enter twice. Thats somethign different :)!

Comment: I see now.  You are looking for a way to extend or hoping it fires an event you can listen for and inject new functionality?

Comment: https://www.tinymce.com/docs/advanced/events/  lists different which you could likely take advantage of to track how many times in a row enter has been pressed, and should get you to your destination.

Comment: what if you could manage to `press enter once -> add <br>`, and after that you press enter again to further separate the text with another <br>, and another, etc. do you really need, with the second return, to remove that <br> and append a new <p>. in short: would two <br>'s suffice instead of a <p>?

Answer (score 0):

I was browsing the `tinymce.js` file and I think I found the main piece of code that deals with handling the `enter` key events:

```
var insert$3 = function (editor, evt) {
    $_3fpic86uje5o2r2r.getAction(editor, evt).fold(function () {
        $_1esduy3wje5o2qhl.insert(editor, evt);
    }, function () {
        $_54gcs16qje5o2r1x.insert(editor, evt);
    }, $_enfhkv6je5o2ply.noop);
};
```

and replaced it with:

```
var insert$3 = function (editor, evt) {
    $_3fpic86uje5o2r2r.getAction(editor, evt).fold(function () { 
        //this seems to be where Shift + Enter was being run
    }, function () {
        if (editor.lastKeyPressed === 13)            
            $_54gcs16qje5o2r1x.insert(editor, evt);  
        else
            $_1esduy3wje5o2qhl.insert(editor, evt);  
    }, $_enfhkv6je5o2ply.noop);
};
```

and `editor.lastKeyPressed` takes its value from:

```
init_instance_callback: function(editor) {
    editor.on('keydown', function(e) {
        editor.lastKeyPressed = e.which;
    });
}
```

add previous chunk as a parameter of your init function, found it [here](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/advanced/events/)

and so:

- ***Shift + Enter*** to ***Pressing enter once***
- ***Enter*** to ***Pressing enter twice***

It is a bit of a hack, I know, but I hope it puts you on track towards a more elegant solution